# VueJs component template v-bind class como parametro

Tags: vue.js

Tengo una situación medio rara, donde la documentación que menciona el error: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties no me está siendo de utilidad o no la estoy entendiendo como se supone.

Sin más detalles que agregar por el momento, vamos al código:

**Componente:**

```
Vue.component("product-card", {
  props: ["title", "price", "url", "sku", "retina", "image", "cssclass"],
    template: `<a v-bind:class="cssclass" v-bind:href= "url">
            <img
                v-bind:alt = "title"
                v-bind:src = "image"
                v-bind:srcset = "retina"
            />
            <h3 class = "fx-product-carousel-cell__title"> 
            {{title}}
            </h3>
            <div class = "fx-price" > {{price}} </div>
            </a>`
});
```

**Uso del componente:**

```
 <product-card v-for="product in introductionProducts"
      v-bind:key="product.ProductCode"
      v-bind:title="product.Name"
      v-bind:url="getURL(product.ProductCode)"
      v-bind:image="getSrc(product.ProductCode)"
      v-bind:retina="getRetina(product.ProductCode)"
      v-bind:cssclass="fx-display-board__item"
      v-bind:price="product.Price"
 ></product-card>
```

**Y me da el error:**

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "fx" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "display" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "board__item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "fx" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "display" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "board__item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "fx" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "display" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "board__item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "fx" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "display" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
[Vue warn]: Property or method "board__item" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>) vue.js:597:7
```

**Intentos de solución:**

Se me ocurrió que quizás el problema viene con el nombre de la clase, sí, por los guiones, entonces reemplacé el nombre de la clase por

```
v-bind:cssclass="fxdisplayboarditem"
```

No, no funcionó.

Si la propiedad cssclass la muevo de manera estática al template del componente quedando:

```
<a class="fx-display-board__item" v-bind:href= "url">
```

Previamente siendo:

```
<a v-bind:class="cssclass" v-bind:href= "url">
```

Funciona, sin embargo ¿cuál es el objetivo de crear un componente? Que sea re-utilizable... ¿Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparto la solución para quienes andan con el mismo problema.

Reemplazar:

```
v-bind:cssclass="fx-display-board__item"
```

Por:

```
v-bind:cssclass="'fx-display-board__item'"
```

Nótese las comillas simples dentro de las comillas dobles para el nombre de la clase.

Conversando con el buen @gbianchi, la solución era aún más simple!

Componente:

```
Vue.component("product-card", {
  props: ["title", "price", "url", "sku", "retina", "image"],
    template: `<a v-bind:href= "url">
            <img
                v-bind:alt = "title"
                v-bind:src = "image"
                v-bind:srcset = "retina"
            />
            <h3 class = "fx-product-carousel-cell__title"> 
            {{title}}
            </h3>
            <div class = "fx-price" > {{price}} </div>
            </a>`
});
```

Uso en el HTML:

```
<product-card v-for="product in introductionProducts"
      v-bind:key="product.ProductCode"
      v-bind:title="product.Name"
      v-bind:url="getURL(product.ProductCode)"
      v-bind:image="getSrc(product.ProductCode)"
      v-bind:retina="getRetina(product.ProductCode)"
      class="fx-display-board__item"
      v-bind:price="product.Price"
 ></product-card>
```

Comment: Aca hay 2 temas. primero no es necesario que los hijos tengan un class definido, ya que si lo definis a la altura del padre, el hijo lo puede tomar tranquilamente [mira aca](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Replacing-Merging-with-Existing-Attributes). Despues, el problema son los guiones en el nombre. hay un tema con la nomenclatura de las propiedades por como las trata JS y el DOM.. entonces necesitas las comillas simples, porque esta lleno de - y __. si le sacas todo eso al nombre, y lo pones en pascal-case (FxDisplayBoardItem), va a funcionar tambien

Comment: Hey bro! gracias por tomarte el tiempo en comentar. El detalle es que esa "cssclass" va cambiando de acuerdo al lugar donde se llama, por eso tiene que ser dinámica. Los guiones y los guiones bajos son efecto de una práctica de CSS llamada "BEM" Block Element Modifier https://www.sitepoint.com/title-css-simple-approach-css-class-naming/ Por otro lado, si utilizo FxDisplayBoardItem y le retiro las comillas simples lanza este error: [Vue warn]: Property or method "FxDisplayBoardItem" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render (Esto lo dejo para que la gente evite perder tiempo)

Comment: y definitivamente esa clase tiene que ir entre comillas simples para que funcione  :D

Comment: pero la definiste como prop con ese nombre? quiero creer que si.. pero mejor asegurarse.. y no importa que el class cambie.. los padres del componente pueden cambiar el class sin necesidad de que sea prop

Comment: Acabo de ver que era mucho más simple todavía #ActualizandoRespuesta